# How to remove an element from a set that is in a map

Tags: java, set, maps

I'm trying to remove an element from a set that is in a map but I'm unsure how to do it.

The code I have so far is:

```
public void deleteToValue(String aLocation, String aEquipment)
{      
locationMap.remove(aLocation, aEquipment);
}
```

The map key is the location and the the set is called equipment.

Assume the location is London and I want to remove a bike from the set.

The key and set will always be present so there's no need to check for nulls at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This requires 2 steps:

```
Set<String> equipment = locationMap.get(aLocation) => returns the set
equipment.remove(aEquipment) ==> removes equipment from set.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a map -> `Map<String, Set<String>>` and you want to remove equipment for some location.

Please, consider this code:

```
public void deleteToValue(String aLocation, String aEquipment)
{      
    Set<String> equip = locationMap.get(aLocation);
    if (equip != null) {
       equip.remove(aEquipment);
    }   
}
```

When calling map `.get(..key..)` method, it returns a value associated with a provided key, in your case, your value is `Set<>`. 
So, to remove something from the set, firtly you need to read it from the map by key -> `Set<String> equip = locationMap.get(aLocation);` and then remove the required item from the `Set` -> `equip.remove(aEquipment);`